# How to remove the Debug Assertion Error in Visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a program to read the names of files in a directory. The code runs in the CodeBlocks IDE but the same gives me a Debug Assertion Error when I run it in Visual Studio.

I have added **_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS** in the **Preprocessor properties** because without it strerror() gave me an error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void listdirs(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *mask)
{
wchar_t *fspec1 = { L'\0' }, *fname = { L'\0' };
WIN32_FIND_DATA     dta;
HANDLE              hDta;
DWORD dLastError;
LPCWSTR fspec = reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(fspec1);
char *buff = { '\0' };

swprintf(fspec1, 100, L"%s/%s", dir, mask);


if ((hDta = FindFirstFile(fspec, &dta)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

    dLastError = GetLastError();
  printf("The error : %s\n", strerror(dLastError));



}

else {
    do {
        if (!(dta.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {
            printf("%ws\n", dta.cFileName);
        }
        else
        {
        if (wcscmp(dta.cFileName,L".") !=0 && wcscmp(dta.cFileName,L"..")!=0)
            {
                swprintf(fname, 100,  L"%s", dta.cFileName);
                listdirs(fname, mask);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hDta, &dta));

    FindClose(hDta);
}
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    listdirs(L"C:\\windows\\system32\\Tasks", L"\\.*"); 
    return 0;
}
```

The output should either print an error message if it cannot access the folder or print the filenames. In either case, I only get a debug assertion error.

Comment: Time to run a debug build in the debugger, to catch the assertion when it happens and to locate where in *your* code it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the definitions

```
wchar_t *fspec1 = { L'\0' }, *fname = { L'\0' };
```

you say that both `fspec1` and `fname` are pointers, pointing to `NULL`. Attempting to dereference these pointers in any way will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

And you do dereference these pointers, and even attempt to write to where these null-pointers are pointing. For example with

```
swprintf(fspec1, 100, L"%s/%s", dir, mask);
```

You need to allocate memory for these pointers to actually point to. Or define them as suitably sized arrays:

```
wchar_t fspec1[100], fname[100];
```